# Enabled Disabled Select option based on previous dropdown?

Tags: html, jquery, dropdown, html-select

i have 2 dropdown, lets say select 1 and select 2, the scenario is
when user select dropdown on **select 1** and choose A, so on **select 2**, option A will be disabled.

Here is my code, actually this is working,

but i have a condition when user will edit the dropdown, on select 1 user already choose A but select 2 still not selected, what i want is the option A in select 2 must be disabled, but currently it still enable

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/q3mu7x2w/

```js
$("#pr_bundling").change(function(){

    $("#pr_cross").find("option").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $("#pr_cross [value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");

    $('#pr_cross').not(this).has('option[value="'+  this.value + '"]:selected').val('noselect29');



})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>select 1</h3>
  <select class="form-control" id="pr_bundling">
    <option value='noselect99' selected >Select</option>
    <option value="A" selected>A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<br>

<h3>select 2</h3>
 <select class="form-control" id="pr_cross">
      <option value='noselect29' selected >Select</option>
     <option value="A">A</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="D">D</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable options based on previous selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909907/disable-options-based-on-previous-selects)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$('#pr_cross').not(this).has('option[value="'+  this.value + '"]:selected').val('noselect29');`?

Comment: if user change anything on select 1, the select 2 will be reset

Comment: i have a condition when user want to edit, user already choose A on select 1, so on select 2 option A will be disabled, the link above still doesnt answer, because when i choose Milk as selected, in the select 2 milk still enable

Comment: @ezles88 `milk` is **not** enabled => https://jsfiddle.net/e9zwm0cj/ => its the solution from that duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ensure that the initial selection from `#pr_bundling` is disabled on page load by moving your update code into a function and calling that on `$(document).ready` (either directly or via [`.trigger`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)).

```js
function update_select() {
  let selected = $('#pr_bundling').val();
  $("#pr_cross").find("option").each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
  });
  $("#pr_cross [value=" + selected + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pr_bundling").change(update_select);
  update_select();
  // or you can trigger the change handler:
  // $("#pr_bundling").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>select 1</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="pr_bundling">
  <option value='noselect99' selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A" selected>A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<br>

<h3>select 2</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="pr_cross">
  <option value='noselect29' selected>Select</option>
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $("#pr_bundling").trigger('change'); can be used as well.

Comment: @thinktwice good point; I've updated the answer with a note about that and included the code as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is wrong while disabling the value of select 2.

```
$("#pr_cross option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bs7h0got/

Comment: the value in select 2 still not disabled bro

Comment: You have written the code on change, Try to change the select 1 value and it should reflect accordingly on select 2.

Comment: As I have mentioned on Nick's answers adding $("#pr_bundling").trigger('change'); at the end of your javascript would solve the issue as well.